# Filtering columns with SQL reserved keywords as column name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, reserved-words

A set of data is uploaded by my colleague and I have to filter the data by date. Unfortunately my colleague used reserved words of year and month for uploading the data so the data in database looks like this:

```
babyname     year  month  gender
-----------  ----  -----  ------
Sarah        2018  2      f
Jack         2016  5      m
James        2017  7      m
Susan        2017  1      f
```

I am going to filter baby girls name who were born from or after April 2017. I wrote following query but it does not filter the data by date at all:

```
SELECT * FROM babytable
WHERE
gender='f' 
AND
(("year"=2017 AND "month">3) OR "year"=2018);
```

Would you please let me know what is my mistake.
Many Thanks

Comment: The query correctly returns Sarah - what exactly is your question? Correctly quoting column names that use (non-reserved) keywords as you did will not change the result: http://rextester.com/PJGVS72570

Comment: Your query returns Sarah, as expected!

Comment: You can simplify and do `where gender = 'f' and  ("year", "month") >= (2017,4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make the column names into strings, your `WHERE gender = 'f'` condition has the correct format. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM babytable
WHERE
gender='f' 
AND
((year=2017 AND month>3) OR year=2018);
```

Comment: Syntax error... YEAR and MONTHS are reserved words, so these columns need to be delimited.

Comment: @jarlh: no, they don't need to be quoted. They are keywords, but they non-reserved keywords: http://rextester.com/PJGVS72570

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, they aren't? Sorry for jumping to conclusions. (According to the ANSI/ISO SQL spec they are reserved.)

Comment: @jarlh: see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=83e353fd76c30d4a60bfe41d3ae6da55)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    births 
WHERE
    gender = 'f' 
    AND ((year = 2017 AND month > 4) OR (year > 2017))
```

Alternatively you could convert the `year` and `month` columns into dates before comparing:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    births 
WHERE
    gender = 'f' 
    AND to_date(year || '-' || month, 'YYYY-MM') > '2017-04-30'
```